# Using a pointer to Isolate in libuv worker thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, v8, libuv, node.js-addon

I try to develop an async Node.js addon that works with an Isolate.

Consider this example code:

```
struct Work {
  uv_work_t  request;
  Persistent<Function> callback;
  Isolate * isolate;
};

// called in worker thread
static void WorkAsync(uv_work_t *req)
{
    Work *work = static_cast<Work *>(req->data);
    HeapStatistics stats;
    work->isolate->GetHeapStatistics(&stats);

    // ... do other stuff ...
}

// called by in main thread
static void WorkAsyncComplete(uv_work_t *req, int status)
{
    Isolate * isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    v8::HandleScope handleScope(isolate);
    Work *work = static_cast<Work *>(req->data);

    // ... do other stuff ...

    work->callback.Reset();
    delete work;
}

void RunAsync(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&args) {
    Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
    Work * work = new Work();
    work->request.data = work;
    work->isolate = isolate;

    Local<Function> callback = Local<Function>::Cast(args[0]);
    work->callback.Reset(isolate, callback);

    // kick of the worker thread
    uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(), &work->request, WorkAsync, WorkAsyncComplete);
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(Undefined(isolate));
}

void setup(Handle <Object> exports, Handle<Object> module) {
  NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "run", RunAsync);
}

NODE_MODULE(addon, setup)
```

My question: is it safe to pass a pointer to current Isolate to a worker thread (for read-only purposes)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Scott Frees (the author of **C++ and Node.js Integration** ebook: https://scottfrees.com/ebooks/nodecpp/):

To be honest, I've never tried to do that.  It seems to me that it should be fine - as long as you are only making calls on the isolate and not actually modifying anything within it.

Generally, if you try to do anything in violation with the V8 threading model, it will generate an exception - so if it's not, then I'd assume it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. However, you are the responsable of the safety. You need to be sure that Isolate is leaved from the parent thread and unlocked. Then it can be used (Entred) in the worker thread.